Deploying firebase cloud functions using Python AND Javascript?
I am trying to use both python and js in my firebase cloud functions.
One folder that I have in the project and that works is called /functions and contains only js code. This deploys and run fine.
I use firebase deploy --only functions:whateverNameOfFunction to deploy.
Now I have create a second folder which is called /python which I want to have python code in.
I have created a file inside with working code which I have tasted locally.
I want to deploy this python cloud function now. I do not wish to start a new project and use the new generation so that I can just select Python at the start of project creation when prompted.
What can I do? I have read the documentation and some examples but I do not see command examples of how this should be deployed. Is it possible at all?

So it turns out, indeed you can.
You can just do firebase init and create a new project with python which will not interfere(at least on my end it did not). It is important that a venv folder be created and you activate venv.
